# What to make of solana metrics logs for quic client

Tags: solana-program, transactions, send-transaction

As some context to my issues, I have the solana metrics crate printing logs whilst trying to send transactions from a rust client. Is there any information regarding to the nature of the various errors? For example, regularly getting the errors below:

`Error sending to 198.244.212.39:8009 with id 139634701876928, error WriteError(ConnectionLost(ApplicationClosed(ApplicationClose { error_code: 0, reason: b"" }))`

`Failed to send transaction async to 147.75.56.83:9009, error: Custom("ConnectionError(TimedOut)")`